# Ctrontab -e does not execute commands

Tags: cron

I am not getting it but below part is taken from the sudo crontab -e but none of the commands are executed as scheduled. I tried with sudo and without (last should be correct, as it runs as root). If I execute the commands manually with sudo, all three do work.

```
# create SD backup every Wed at 1am:
0 1 * * 3 sudo sh /home/pi/bkup_rpimage/bkup_rpimage.sh start -c /media/pi/RaspiSDBack/rpi_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).img
# copy SD backup to NAS every 15th at 4-30 am:
30 4 15 * * sudo cp -n -r /media/pi/RaspiSDBack/* /home/pi/QNAP/PI_Backup/
# daily reboot at 4 am:
0 4 * * * sudo /sbin/shutdown -r +5
```

Anyone an idea? I am new to this and can't get any further, currently.

Comment: The last is exactly, what I do: Sudo crontab -e - sorry, will add it to the initial post

Comment: if it's root's crontab then there's no point in sudo

Comment: Then the question is what kind of system it is and what the cron daemon looks like.

Comment: I see the letters qnap in there which would imply [some rather specific instructions regarding cron](https://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Add_items_to_crontab).